# Trying to get day of week (mon, tue etc..) in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using a linqdatasource for a gridview.
On linqdatasource_selecting I wrote the following query to pass to `e.Result`

```
Select o.localID, o.delivery_date, 
dow = o.delivery_date.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString("ddd"), o.created_by
o.customer_name, o.customer.OrderNum
Order By delivery_date Descending
```

I'm getting to the following error

> Method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' has no supported
>   translation to SQL.

I've seen people saying to make the projection of `o.delivery_date.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString("ddd")`
after getting the results with .ToLists

The problem with this is that I will loose the efficiency of paging from the gridview since linq will get results from all pages instead of the one the gridiew is requesting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need to use the ToString in your linq query.  If you just select `o.delivery_date.Value.DayOfWeek` you should be able to bind to the enum name when you set up your grid view

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day of Week">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Enum.GetName(typeof(System.DayOfWeek),Convert.ToInt32(Eval("dow"))) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: `SqlFunctions` available for `LINQ2Entities`.

Comment: Good spot...pays to read the question! ;o)  I'll mod my answer.

Comment: tried that. get error : `This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.`

Comment: @boruchsiper - check the update, hopefully it will be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do, but I would recommend not to format the date in your query.

`DayOfWeek.ToString("ddd")` belongs to the presentation layer, not to the data layer. Your query should return a full `DateTime` object, so anyone using the query can do what they want with it (display day of the week or not, using American format, English format...)

Only in your view (assuming this is an MVC website) you should format the date to appear the way you want.

With regards to pagination you should use `Skip()` and `Take()` methods. For instance, if you want to display page 6 and there are 20 records per page:

```
var result = (Select o.localID, o.delivery_date, 
dow = o.delivery_date, o.created_by
o.customer_name, o.customer.OrderNum
Order By delivery_date Descending).Skip(100).Take(20)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you formatting string as the "ddd" ? this should like -

```
Select o.localID, o.delivery_date,
dow = o.delivery_date.Value.ToString("ddd"), o.created_by
o.customer_name, o.customer.OrderNum
Order By delivery_date Descending
```

Comment: You're right about that. get the same error though either way

Comment: @boruchsiper, is **o.delivery_date.Value** of DateTime Type ? or what ?

Comment: o.delivery_date.Value  is Of Date